# Javascript regex to get param value

Tags: javascript, regex, parameters

I'm working on a code base someone else built and the search function uses this to get the parameter from the url to place as a value to search against. I've tried re-writing it, modifiying it, and everything else possible and can't figure out what is going on with the reutrn value from the function.

Here's the function

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    console.log(name);
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&#;]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    console.log(results);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var part = getParameterByName('part_name');
```

The value of location.search is `?part_number=1234&go=GO`

Then in the input box `part_name` if I type 1234 to be the value of the passed in parameter it will only show 12. However typing in other random numbers it will sometimes show them all correctly. If I type 124 as the search param then it displays correctly as searching against 124.

Is there something wrong with one of these regex statments that could be causing this, or is this something on the server side? The PHP seems fine on  the backend but I'm not savvy on the Regex used in the Javascript code.

**EDIT**:

A testing snippet:

```js
function getParameterByName(loc, name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += "Name: " + name + "&nbsp; - ";
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&#;]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(loc);
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += results + "<br/>";
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var part = getParameterByName('?part_number=1234&go=GO', 'part_number');
var part2 = getParameterByName('?part_name=12&go=GO', 'part_name');
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Comment: Please provide the `location.search` and `name` values. What is `1234`? A name? Then, what is the location?

Comment: I am sorry for making another edit, but please check: all the numbers are obtained correctly: for `part_number`, `1234` is returned, and for `part_name`, it is `12`.